# Service banner checking for vulnerabilities offline

Tags: fingerprinting

Has anybody seen a tool where you can collect Service banners from something like nmap, output them to a file, the vuln vulnerability checks offline?

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed tool would perform a lookup of the version numbers against a database of known vulnerable versions. That could be scripted by hand and checked against something like metasploit, NSE, or exploit-db.com (if by 'offline', you mean 'away from the targets').

This would be very cursory in nature, so I doubt a tool pre-exists, but can easily be done by hand.